# Irreducibility of q-factorial plus 1

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, q-analogs

Is it true that $[n]_q! + 1$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ for all positive integers $n$ ?

I checked that this is true for $n$ up to $20$.

Here $[n]_q! := 1 (1 + q) (1 + q + q^2) \cdots (1 + q + \cdots + q^{n-1})$ is the [q-factorial.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-Factorial.html)

Comment: Still true upto $n=60$

Comment: Verified for $n\leq 117$. Also tried most common irreducibility criteria and only ones that worked are not scalable to generic $n$ (they need specific and often large prime for each $n$ to prove). Then, monic polynomial with prime constant coefficient (this one is always with $p=2$) can be reducible only if it has roots inside (or on) as well as outside of unit circle (interesting observation by @QiaochuYuan ). Unfortunately these polynomials satisfy that condition so you cannot rule out reducibility this way either...

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324865/irreducibility-of-q-factorial-plus-1